# Get a 404 error when deploying my webapplication on a tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Created my first webapplication using Servlet and a tomcat server. Basic concept is people can register themselves to be members of a fanclub and can then see who the people are that registered.

When I deploy the tomcat server I get to my indexpage just fine, same for my member register webpage. But then when I click the submit button it should redirect to my Servlet and add the given credentials to it's database and print them out.

This is where I get my error 404 with description: Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I believe the problem has something to do with the way my webpages are linked. Although I'm honestly not really sure at this point.

Help is greatly appreciated.

full code on github: https://github.com/pieterjan-dubois/opdracht_get_post_website

```
@WebServlet("/opdracht_get_post_website_war_exploded/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private RegistratieDB dataBank = new RegistratieDB();
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                String naam = request.getParameter("Voornaam");
                String achternaam = request.getParameter("achternaam");
                String loginnaam = request.getParameter("loginnaam");
                String passwoord = request.getParameter("passwoord");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                String niveau = request.getParameter("niveau");

                Registratie voegToe = new Registratie(naam, achternaam, loginnaam, passwoord, email, niveau);
                dataBank.add(voegToe);

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("leden.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("leden.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}




 INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.99
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 11 2019 13:15:59 UTC
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 7.0.99.0
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\jbr
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           11.0.3+12-b304.56
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            JetBrains s.r.o
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_99_opdracht_get_post_website
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\OneDrive\Documents\school\Toegepaste informatica 19-20\semester 2\web2\tomcat
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_99_opdracht_get_post_website\conf\logging.properties
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_99_opdracht_get_post_website\jmxremote.password
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_99_opdracht_get_post_website\jmxremote.access
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_99_opdracht_get_post_website
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\OneDrive\Documents\school\Toegepaste informatica 19-20\semester 2\web2\tomcat
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\OneDrive\Documents\school\Toegepaste informatica 19-20\semester 2\web2\tomcat\temp
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 439 ms
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.99
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 74 ms
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:08 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:09 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [233] milliseconds.
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\OneDrive\Documents\school\Toegepaste informatica 19-20\semester 2\web2\tomcat\webapps\manager]
Mar 10, 2020 8:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\piete_8alqa94\OneDrive\Documents\school\Toegepaste informatica 19-20\semester 2\web2\tomcat\webapps\manager] has finished in [98] ms
```

Comment: What do access logs say? Can you print them in your quesion ?

Comment: Where can I find those?

Comment: <Tomcat_directory>/logs. The main log file is the catalina.out file where you can find error messages.

Comment: Could you remove in this line https://github.com/pieterjan-dubois/opdracht_get_post_website/blob/master/web/registratie.jsp#L32 the first "/" and try again.

Comment: Will do @SHoko and Dawid D I restarted tomcat server and navigated until I got the problem and copied those logs.

Comment: When removing the first / like you said gives me this: https://imgur.com/2tbBL8w

Comment: Ok, I understand that you `action` entry will be "opdracht_get_post_website_war_exploded/Servlet"

Comment: when including the first / I get localhost:8080/opdracht_get_pos_website_exploded/Servlet                       
with the / removed it's localhost:8080/opdracht_get_pos_website_exploded/opdracht_get_pos_website_exploded/Servlet

Comment: Could you update this line too https://github.com/pieterjan-dubois/opdracht_get_post_website/blob/c141cd0ab4173f1f3f84b45e5f9d7b80644ead4a/src/ui/controller/Servlet.java#L15? 
Would be `@WebServlet("/Servlet")`

Comment: With first / removed and @webServlet("/Servlet") I get this pressing the register button: https://imgur.com/tdcVqoc

Comment: When I do action="Servlet" instead of opdracht_get_post_website_war_exploded/Servlet in the registratie.jsp file I get this error might help you more: https://imgur.com/9UvkVgh

Comment: I figured it out :) thanks for helping me in the right direction, I can finally sleep @SHoko